# Unable to force restart mac server by remote because no free ram left

Tags: ssh, mac-osx-server, remote

I have a Mac server and now I'm unable to remote or even to SSH to reboot since its out of free ram and I can't use SSH to force it restart or not even be able to remote to the screen to restart the server

Is there anyway to achieve this other than call the internet server center to hard reset??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have an XServe and you configured the [Lights-Out Management](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2773) system so you can access it remotely: Nope.

Comment: I was able to connect to my server but today I saw the ram going down till like none left and suddenly got disconnected and can't even reconnect :(